# Closed as Too Localized

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The Too Localized reason for closing a question seems to general. I'm still not sure why my question was closed: [Database Implementations of ORDER BY in a Subquery](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82930/database-implementations-of-order-by-in-a-subquery)

> Too localized - this could be because your code has a typo, basic
>   error, or is not relevant to most of our audience.

There are no typos / errors so I can only assume the "not relevant" part, and that implementations of SQL rather than SQL queries should be on SO rather than here?

I added comments and edited the question to try and make it of more use to a general audience, but no further insights as to why it was put on-hold were given prior to closing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way the question was originally written, I voted to close as too localized because *"it is not relevant to most of our audience"*. That doesn't mean it isn't an interesting or good question in general, by the way.

After the edit, my view was that the question is now *just about* on-topic, so I voted to reopen. The question has three of five required reopen votes at this time. I have flagged the question for a moderator because the question might not have been reviewed by enough people with the reopen privilege. We'll see what happens. Thanks for raising this on meta.

Update: the question has been reopened now.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully that would have happened without posting on meta. I had edited the question and commented as suggested when on-hold, but from my perspective (without seing any reopen votes) it had seemed as though on-hold led inevitably to closed.